# How to debug clangCodeGen in LLVM project

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I get source of LLVM and make a project on Visual Studio as guiding in https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html
I would like to debug clangCodeGen to know how IR is generated or Code Generation do in LLVM. However there is no main() method or something like this in clangCodeGen project. 
Do you have any suggestion for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clangCodeGen` project is a static library, so it doesn't have `main` function and you can't debug it right away.

What you need to do is:

1. Come up with `clang` invocation you want to debug. For instance, `clang test.c`.
2. Append `-v` flag and look at the command's output. It should contain large `clang` command starting with `"full\\path\\\\to\\clang.exe" -cc1 ...`
3. Choose whatever project you like in your solution, open its Properties windows and go to `Debugging` tab.
4. Set `Command` field to `"full\\path\\\\to\\clang.exe"` and `Command Arguments` to the rest of `clang -v` output.
5. Build the solution.
6. Right-click on the chosen project and select `Start debugging`.